# Zsh's yank-pop is not working

Tags: bash, zsh

In **bash**, you can kill words (Alt-Backspace) or lines (Ctrl-k), and yank them back later with C-y, and cycling the kill-ring with Alt-y.

Now when I'm using **zsh**, it is weird that Alt-y is not working (nothing happens when I press it), although I've set it to use emacs keybindings (bindkey -e).

Any ideas how to fix it?

`zsh --version` returns 4.3.12

`bindkey | grep yank` shows that yank-pop is already bound to ^[y (Alt-y).

**UPDATED: debugging results**

A. How do I test that Alt-y is not working?

1. I type 'abc'
2. I kill it by pressing `Alt-Backspace`
3. I type 'efg'
4. I kill it again by Alt-Backspace
5. I press `Ctrl-y` to yank it back - and I got 'efg'
6. I press `Alt-y` - and I should have got 'abc', but it remained as 'efg' - nothing happened.

B. `M-x yank-pop` is not working either.

C. I run `zsh -f` and `bindkey -e`. Then I try the debug process again - **it works this time!**

So I guess there must be something wrong with my .zshrc - I'm gonna bisect it out.

One ore thing to mention: I'm using the `oh-my-ssh` package with the following plugins enabled: `git django extract gem heroku history-substring-search pip rvm`

Thanks Gilles for the `zsh -f` trick - I didn't realize that the problem was in the configuration files.

Comment: It works for me. Where did you get your zsh binary? What happens if you run `zsh -f`? How exactly do you determine that `M-y` isn't working? What about `M-x yank-pop`?

Comment: @Gilles 1. I installed it from `pacman -S` 2. I've edited my question to include the debug results. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

After bisecting my `.zshrc`, I found that the problem was in the `oh-my-ssh` plugins, namely the `history-substring-search` plugin.

So I disabled it and <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> works well.

Comment: Can you please accept your own answer, so this question doesn't remain open?